# Blockly games translation to a new language not happening

Tags: language-translation, blockly

I downloaded the the zip file of blockly games from GitHub to translate it to a new language [tir](https://www.ethnologue.com/language/tir).

I have built it and did the following:

1. I added `tir.json` (a file that contains the translations) to the folder `~blockly-games-master/json`.
2. Changed all `en` entries in `~makefile` to ‘tir’.
3. Added an entry for `tir` in `~appengine/js/lib-games.js`
4. Added an entry for `tir` in ~appengine/common/boot.js

However, when I open `index.html` in a web browser, translations are not happening. I can see the new language listed in the dropdown list. But when I click it, English is displayed. I am new to such translations and this is taking me long to figure out. Can somebody please help me figure out or give me references to similar tasks?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using same block_compressed you need to rebuild to create new compressed file using build.py or link your json seperately and check.